# Ants, cylinders and shape operator

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

For an oriented surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the curvature tensor can be expressed as
$$ R(X,Y)Z = \langle L(Y),Z \rangle L(X) - \langle L(X),Z \rangle L(Y) $$

where $X,Y,Z$ are vectors fields on the surface and $L$ is the shape operator.

I was wondering whether an inverse relationship exists, that allows to write the shape operator $L$ as a function of the curvature tensor.

I am a little confused in this regard, as I know that the curvature tensor is an intrinsic property of the surface, ultimately deriving from its metric, whereas the shape operator describes how the surface is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In other words, if such a relationship existed, that allows the shape operator to be reconstructed from the curvature tensor (so from the metric) an ant living on a cilinder, that can calculate the curvature tensor (and, of course, the gaussian curvature) on each point, could also calculate the shape operator and ultimately reconstruct the embedding of his 2 dimensional world in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Any help?
thanks

Comment: If you know the determinant of a matrix, do you know the matrix? How would your ant know whether she is on a plane, a cylinder, a cone, etc.? And must a surface of constant curvature $1$ locally be a sphere?

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin thanks for your comment. This is indeed what I understood as well. Cylinder, plane and cone all have zero gaussian curvature. I was confused by the fact that in cilindrical coordinates the first fundamental form is different from the identity matrix. But this is just a matter of coordinates and does not imply anything else, as the first fundamental form that the ant will measure locally wil depend on the coordinate system used, and, regardless coordinates, the ant will still measure zero gaussian curvature and Riemann tensor. Right?

Comment: Right. ………………..